# I want to know the USB information

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos

How can i come to know that when a USB was connected and if any files from that USB are copied to the system or not?
I have tried for dmesg command but it is showing me a lots of information.

Answer (score 0):

You can't find out the information you are looking for.

There is no OS log when files are copied (but if you know the name of a file you can search for it to see if the OS can find it).

You may be able to get information about when USB devices were inserted in your device with the command

```
cat /var/log/kern.log | grep -a "USB device" | less
```

Comment: /var/log/syslog also has about 20 lines added when a USB device is inserted. Looking for "Attached SCSI removable disk" has the advantage to also take in account other connections (Bluetooth...) and distinguish from other USB devices (mice, tablets, novelty missile launchers).